# Microsoft Graph - Filter Start/DateTime

Tags: node.js, datetime, microsoft-graph-api

Working with the nodejs library for Microsoft Graph, trying to query my calendar and return the next 5 events.

Query setup:

```
client
        .api('/me/events')
        .header('X-AnchorMailbox', email)
        .top(5)
        .filter('Start/DateTime ge 2017-05-26T00:00:00')
        .select('subject,start,end')
        .orderby('start/dateTime DESC')
```

When executed Graph replies with:

```
"code":"BadRequest","message":"The DateTimeOffset text '2017-05-26T00:00:00.000' should be in format 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss('.'s+)?(zzzzzz)?' and each field value is within valid range."
```

Does `2017-05-26T00:00:00` not match `'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss('.'s+)?(zzzzzz)?'`?

Comment: Possibly related: [OData/odata.net#534](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/534)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple mistake:

```
.filter(`Start/DateTime ge '2017-05-26T00:00:00'`)
```